# Is it possible to create a generic method that is suitable for different classes in Java?

Tags: java, generics, java-8, code-reuse

I have different classes that have a structure like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    private String name;
    private List<International> internationalList;
}
```

What I want is to have a generic method that given a localization (example: "en-us") it searches at the internationalList and set the name with the correct language.

Example:

```
 public MyClass myMethod(String local, MyClass object){

            for (International international : object.internationalList){
                if(local.equals(international.language)){
               object.name = international.translation
         }
      }
    return myObject;
 }
```

I didn't want to re-write this code to every class. Is it possible to create a generic method that is suitable for all classes that have this structure?

Comment: No, unless you can establish a common contract among those classes

Comment: Can you make all those classes implement a common interface?

Comment: did you think to use an interface or abstract class?

Comment: Yes, I can make those classes implement a common interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Define your interfaces**

You can create a interface that will be implemented by `MyClass`

```
public interface LocationAware {
    String getName();
    void setName(String name);
    List<International> getInternationals();
    void setInternationals(List<International> internationals);
}
```

Then implement the class like

```
public static class MyClass implements LocationAware {
    private String name;
    private List<International> internationalList;
    // getter and setters
}
```

You can also use an interface for `International` and implement the class.

```
public interface International {
    String getLanguage();
    String getTranslation();
}
```

---

**Using a helper method**

And you would have the helper method with generics, in any class that you want, e.g. `StaticClass`.

```
public static <T extends LocationAware> T changeLocationName(String local, T object) {
    for (International international : object.getInternationals()) {
        if(local.equals(international.getLanguage())) {
            object.setName(international.getTranslation());
        }
    }
    return object;
}
```

That can be called with:

```
StaticClass.changeLocationName("en-us", myClass);
```

---

**Using a default method**

Since you are already using an interface you can have a default method that gives you the same functionallity without a helper method.

```
public interface LocationAware {
    default void changeLocationName(String local) {
        for (International international : getInternationals()) {
            if(local.equals(international.getLanguage())) {
                setName(international.getTranslation());
            }
        }
    }
    String getName();
    void setName(String name);
    List<International> getInternationals();
    void setInternationals(List<International> internationals);
}
```

And just use the class method:

```
MyClass myClass = new Myclass(); // create and add name and internationals
myClass.changeLocationName("en-us"); // then change the location
```

Here you can decide many other ways on how to handle `local`, you can for instance, store the value, and when you use `getName()`, return the current name dinamically, so you don't change the current name every time, (can use a map for little performance gain also).

```
public interface LocationAware {
    default String getName() {
        return getInternationals().get(getLocal());
    }
    void setName(String local);
    String getLocal();
    void setLocal(String local);
    Map<String, International> getInternationals();
    void setInternationals(Map<String, International> internationals);
}
```

*note: you should handle the cases where the location dos not exists*

Answer (score 0):

Here is a static method that solves the problem without generics.

```
public static String lookUpName(String locale, String List<International> list) {
  for (International international : list) {
    if (local.equals(international.language) {
      return international.translation;
    }
  }
  return null; //or “” if that is preferred 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be considered more of a comment, but I wanted to add sufficient detail which wouldn't fit in a comment.

It's not clear which class contains `myMethod(...)`, but the approach appears to be supporting internationalization **externally** from `MyClass` which contains the data.  This breaks the Tell Don't Ask principle.

A more OOP approach would be to have `MyClass` know how to do its own translation. For example:

```
public class NameTranslator {
   // constructor loads the List (or Map)

    public String translate(String locale, String name) {
       ...
    }
}
```

where `MyClass` is aware of it's locale, and uses the translator:

```
public class MyClass {
    private final NameTranslator translator;
    private final String locale;
    private String name;

    // constructor to set the translator and locale

    public void setName(String name) {
       String translatedName = translator.translate(locale, name);
       if (translatedName != null) {
         this.name = translatedName;
       } else {
         this.name = name;  // or throw an IllegalStateException?
       }
    }

    public String getName() {
      return name;
    }
}
```

So the translator doesn't need to know anything about `MyClass`, or any other class.

Also, a Map would be faster than  List when searching for the item to be translated.

Answer (score 0):

Define a common contract like

```
public interface CommonInterface {
    String getName();
    void setName(String name);
    List<International> getInternational();
}
```

Make all classes implement it. Here's one such class.

```
public class MyClass implements CommonInterface {
    private String name;
    private List<International> internationalList;

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public void setName(String name) {
         this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public List<International> getInternational() {
        return internationalList; //Or create a defensive copy
    }
}
```

Your common method would look like

```
public <T extends CommonInterface> T myMethod(String local, T myObject) {
    for (International international : myObject.getInternational()){
        if(local.equals(international.language)) { //Better to avoid direct access and include getters in International class
            myObject.setName(international.translation);
        }
    }
    return myObject;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an abstract class, mark the method "MyMethod" as static and call it in a static way from the classes where you need it. A simple solution.